# docker to connect with mysql database of host system and dump the sql file into host system and then host a web application

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, dockerfile, supervisord

I am new to Docker but i have read quite about it. Now my requirement is:
I will give my client a shell script which he would run on a base ubuntu os on a completely new system. The docker image should use the database of host system.  The shell script will do all the prerequisites of installing docker, mysql, etc. and will run a docker image. As the image is not available locally, it will pull from docker repository.

Now my problem is that i dont want to give my client the sql dump file just like that. The dump is included in the image and once the images is run i want the image to connect to the host database and dump the data and then host the webapp.

My docker file is :
    FROM ubuntu:14.04
    MAINTAINER test_manoj
    RUN pip install requirements.txt
    ADD . /home/myapp/

```
RUN sudo apt-get install -y supervisor
WORKDIR /home/myapp/
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 80
cmd ["supervisord", "-c", "/home/myapp/supervisord.conf"]
```

There are some more apt-get install-s but i didnt find it useful to mention here. So basically i am installing nginx, uwsgi, supervisor.
I have exposed port 8000 for socket uwsgi connections and port 80 for nginx.

My docker run command is :

```
docker run --detach --net=host -v /var/run/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock manoj/mydocker
```

I am using -v to connect the host mysql to container's mysql.
I have already found a work around for my problem that is running

```
docker run --rm --detach --net=host -v /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock manoj/mydocker mysq -uroot -proot db_name < dump.sql
```

before the main run command. I know this works but is there any other way to do this? And is there any other way i can use host's mysql without providing -v tag?

Comment: You can make the host's mysql listening on the docker0 interface, but this may or may not be feasible using a shell script depending on the host mysql configuration.

Comment: ya thats not feasible @warmoverflow